# Changing EURO-CORDEX so it can put in the same plot the data and the countries shapes?

Tags: r, copernicus

I'm working with data from the Copernicus climate change forecast and I downloaded the data of predictions for rain and precipitations from here [link](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-hydrology-meteorology-derived-projections?tab=overview). When I import the data as raster class into R I can plot it without any issue

```
archive <- "prAdjust_tmean_rel_QM-EFAS-Meteo-EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp85_r12i1p1_KNMIRACMO22E-v1_degree15_1971-2000_grid5km_v1.nc"
precipitation <- raster(archive)
plot(precipitation)
```

[image]

But when I use it with ggplot and geom_sf this happens

```
sst_df <- as.data.frame(precipitation, xy = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
countries <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf",continent = "Europe",)

ggplot()+
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = sst_df$prAdjust_tmean), data = sst_df)+
  geom_sf(fill = grey(0.9), color = grey(0.6), lwd = 0.2, data = countries)+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", name = "Change")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I know this is because the coords in the original data are changed but I'm incapable of solving it. I tried with this [gitHub](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/651) thread but I can't set the data as an sf and I can't find any more information available on the web about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not solve your issue itself, just wanted to add clarity on this.

I downloaded similar data from your link https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-hydrology-meteorology-derived-projections?tab=overview and what I found is that the `.nc` file does not have a CRS defined. I tried with several packages and I got:

```r
archive <- "prAdjust_tmean_abs_QM-EFAS-Meteo-EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_KNMI-RACMO22E-v1_na_1971-2000_grid5km_v1.nc"
raster::raster(archive)
#> [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named x BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
#> [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named y BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 950, 1000, 950000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0.5, 1000.5, 0.5, 950.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : prAdjust_tmean_abs_QM-EFAS-Meteo-EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_KNMI-RACMO22E-v1_na_1971-2000_grid5km_v1.nc 
#> names      : precipitation..mean. 
#> z-value    : 2000-07-16 
#> zvar       : prAdjust_tmean 

terra::rast(archive)
#> [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named x BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
#> [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named y BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 950, 1000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0.5, 1000.5, 0.5, 950.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source      : prAdjust_tmean_abs_QM-EFAS-Meteo-EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_KNMI-RACMO22E-v1_na_1971-2000_grid5km_v1.nc:prAdjust_tmean 
#> varname     : prAdjust_tmean (precipitation (mean)) 
#> name        : prAdjust_tmean 
#> unit        :         mm/day 
#> time        : 2000-07-16 UTC 

stars::read_ncdf(archive)
#> no 'var' specified, using prAdjust_tmean
#> other available variables:
#>  lon, lat, time, time_bnds
#> Will return stars object with 950000 cells.
#> No projection information found in nc file. 
#>  Coordinate variable units found to be degrees, 
#>  assuming WGS84 Lat/Lon.
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>                              Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.   NA's
#> prAdjust_tmean [mm/d] 0.009193075 1.255257 1.641808 1.616347 1.970122 9.591338 452709
#> dimension(s):
#>      from   to  refsys                      values x/y
#> x       1 1000  WGS 84 [1000x950] -35.03,...,73.94 [x]
#> y       1  950  WGS 84  [1000x950] 23.94,...,72.64 [y]
#> time    1    1 POSIXct              2000-07-16 UTC    
#> curvilinear grid
```

Additionally, the extent is set as `0.5, 1000.5, 0.5, 950.5`, that does not correspond to WGS 84 or EPSG:3035, just to mention some of the usual CRS for Europe.

The documentation of the package is here https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=283549826 and says that the projection is :

> Projection lambert_azimuthal_equal_area (5km); and rotated grid (0.11°)

But I don't know how to make it work with the file itself.